# Windows/Python pygame.error: video system not initialized after adding pygame.init()

Tags: python, pygame

I added some music to my pygame game and pygame.init() to the script to initialize the video system before it is called, but I think the code is so messy that nothing is in the right place even after moving everything to where it needs to be. As a result of this addition, I'm now getting this error still after adding pygame.init():

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\My First game ERROR.py", line 31, 
     in for event in pygame.event.get(): 
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Here is the code that I have written:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            pygame.init()
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
            pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game')
            Game().main(screen)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)     
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)

import time
pygame.mixer.music.load('The Tonight Show Star Wars The Bee Gees Stayin Alive Shortened.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

#class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   # def __init__(self, *groups):
       # super(Player, self.__init__(*groups)
        #self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
       # self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get_size())

    #def update(self):
       # key = pygame

image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
# initialize variables
image_x = 0
image_y = 0

image_x += 0
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        image_x -= 10
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        image_x += 10
if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        image_y -= 10
if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        image_y += 10

screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.mixer.music.stop(52)
```

Comment: to make code more readable always put ALL import at start. And later you can put all classes and functions, and finally `pygame.init()` and rest.

Comment: you mess with class - inside `main()` in `Game()` you execute `Game.main()` ???

Comment: I don't get it. I checked you got answer for this problem in previous question but you still use the same incorrect code. Why ? Don't you read answers to your questions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be `pygame.quit()` inside `while` loop.

`pygame.quit()` uninitializes modules initialized with `pygame.init()` - but it doesn't exit while loop so `while-loop` tries to use `event.get()` in next loop. And then you get problem because you uninitialized modules.

Besides, it makes no sense

```
if event.type == pygame.quit():
```

it has to be

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

`pygame.quit()` is function which ends what `pygame.init()` started.

`pygame.QUIT` is constant value - try `print(pygame.QUIT)` - which you can compare with `event.type`.

We use `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constant values. Read: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Finally, you need rather

```
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)     
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
```

So it exits loop but it doesn't uninitialize modules which you will need in rest of code.